# Preview 4K video on a smaller screen without scaling

Tags: video, display, video-editing, playback, 4k-resolution

I want to test some 4K videos and inspect their detail. However, I don't have a 4K monitor. What I want to do is zoom in the vide to preview parts of it in native resolution. Each pixel of the video (zoomed part) should correspond to a pixel on my monitor.

To make it clear, I understand what 4K is and that it cannot be played 1:1 full-screen on a smaller screen. I don't need to see the whole image full-screen. I just need to see a small part of the video in order to inspect quality.

Edit:
Some time ago I knew video players that allowed making the window any size, if memory serves right. However, when I try this now, all players that I tested do not allow me to stretch their window more than the screen resolution. Can I make a player do this?

I run Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: so essentially 1/4 of the video at actual resulution on say, a 1080p screen? Not sure if it can be done, but what OS you run would be handy here.

Comment: I run Windows 10. What I want to achieve doesn't have to be done in a fancy way. I was trying to simply stretch the video player window, but none of my players allowed doing that over the screen resolution. I searched in their settings to no avail...